# Two way door lock for thin door

Tags: doors, lock, old-house

I'm converting one of the rooms in my 1840 house into an office. The thing is I have 5 kids and need to be able to lock the door so I can have some level of quiet. I also don't want the kids tinkering around in there when I'm not there. (Sharp tools and stuff)

The kicker is I want it to a lock that can be opened on both sides given a key or code. The door is only about 1-1.25 inch thick of solid wood with only an iron latch.

I've been googling and have not found anything that fits the bill. I think I'm looking for a sliding bolt style lock that can be opened from either side. I'm open to other ideas too if they fit the need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not consider a [rim lock](https://www.houseofantiquehardware.com/antique-iron-cast-iron-locks-set-horizontal-a). This is a surface mounted lock and door latch that was typical in 19th century houses.

[image: rim lock]

It is mounted on the inside surface and requires only two small holes drilled through the door - one for the knob spindle and one for the key.

There are old ones around, but you can find reproductions that work the same way.

*Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources*

Comment: I like the idea. Didn't think of that type of lock let alone know the name of it if I had. Thanks for the info. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a bathroom door which is 1 1/8 inch thick, and I managed to install a regular lock on it. (I bought the door second-hand, and didn't realize how thin it was until I took it home and compared it to my other doors.) The lock package said that the minimum thickness is 1 3/8, but I made it work - barely. [I think this is the lock I used,](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Kwikset-Cove-Venetian-Bronze-Privacy-Door-Knob/4712673) or a very similar one.

I used a Forstner bit to drill the hole for the bolt, and then used a round file to carefully expand the hole until it fit. It was  pretty close - the hole wound up being just slightly smaller than the door thickness. I also had to replace the two screws that hold the two halves of the lock together - the stock ones were too long.

Using a rim lock as the other posted suggested is probably a better option, but those can be pricey. You *may* be able to get away with a cheap lock from your local hardware store.

And replacing the whole door is also an option.

[image]

Comment: A viable option but I like the rim lock better. The rim lock keeps in better aesthetics to the house and that keeps the wife happy.